# Near melting thermoplastic material accumulates in the sharper corners. What is this phenomenon?

Tags: melting-point, plastics, viscosity, adhesion, rheology

I have a part made of a thermoplastic material. When I heat it up and cool it down, the dimension of the part changes non-uniformly. Somehow the melted material tries to fill the sharper corners. So for example if there is a corner with a fillet of $r_1$ and wall thickness of $t_1$, after a high temperature experiment the part deforms to $r_2$ and $t_2$ where

$$\left(t_2-t_1\right)<\left(r_1-r_2\right)$$

[image]

I know it has to do with adhesion and capillary, but not knowing that much about chemistry jargon, I'm not able to find the right term for this phenomena. I would appreciate if you could help me know if this phenomena has a name and what parameters control this behaviour?

Comment: It can be probably explained as a tip effect in term of chemical potential. I think.

Comment: @Alchimista any links to know more about this `tip effect`?

Comment: @andselisk I'm sure I saw a comment about  `anisotropic thermoelasticity Hill yield criterion` but it just disappeared!

Comment: I think it is just capillary pressure, as simple as that.

Comment: Some things in this direction: http://chem.atmos.colostate.edu/AT620/Sonia_uploads/ATS620_F11_Lecture8/Lecture8_AT620_090911.ppt

Comment: @Foad Sorry, I read your question again and  realized what I suggested is irrelevant here. One can delete own comments within 5 min:) I agree with Ivan and what you suggested in the question: capillary effect, it's just that simple.

Comment: @andselisk One can delete own comments until _forever_. 5 min is just the limit for edits.

Comment: @andselisk NP. Well, I know it has to do with capillary and rheology of the melted plastics, but was wondering if this specific phenomenon has a name.  Maybe it has been studied before and I can just use the knowledge. instead of throwing experiments.

Comment: Yes of course has to be "capillarity". Though I want say a drop is spherical because of capillarity.  Another link in the same direction http://www.eng.utah.edu/~lzang/images/lecture-8.pdf